# How to read string like a file in Fortran

Tags: fortran

Suppose I have a string like this :

```
character(20) :: str="&                                                                                                                 
&1.2 &                                                                                                                                  
&2. &                                                                                                                                   
&3.32 &                                                                                                                                 
&4.223 &                                                                                                                                
"
```

How can I read the string like a file?

For example, I tried

```
program main
implicit none

character(20) :: str="&                                                                                                                 
&1.2 &                                                                                                                                  
&2. &                                                                                                                                   
&3.32 &                                                                                                                                 
&4.223 &                                                                                                                                
"

integer i
real a

do i=1,4
   read(str,*) a
   print*, a
end do

end program main
```

but I get only the first line every time

```
   1.200000    
   1.200000    
   1.200000    
   1.200000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have four `real`s in your string, but you read it into one real variable (four times). Since every time you start with the same string, you always get the same result.

Maybe you should read the string into an array directly (without a loop):

```
real a(4)

read(str,*) a(1:4)
```

(You can simple write `read(str,*) a`, the range is just given to indicate that `a` is an array here...)